# Regex for splitting a phone number

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to solve a problem as described below:

Given a phone number, split it into country code, local area code and number. The number format is -

```
[Country code]-[Local Area Code]-[Number]
```

Country code consists of 1-3 digits, local area code consists of 1-3 digits and the number is 4-10 digits long (total 12 digits always).

The separator between the 3 parts can be either a '-'(hyphen) or a ' '(space).

Example:

```
Given Number = 1-425-9854706
Result --> Group 1 = 1          --> Country Code
           Group 2 = 425        --> Local Area Code
           Group 3 = 9854706    --> Number
```

The regex i'm using currently for the same is -

```
^(\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{4,10})$
```

I take the result of capture group 1, 2 and 3.

But this regex doesn't match any input test case. I'm using the java.util.regex package if that helps. Please suggest a better regex for the same. More info about the problem on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/split-number

The code i have written is this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        String s;

        String REGEX = "^(\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{4,10})$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

        Matcher matcher;

        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            s = sc.nextLine();
            matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

            list.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3)));

            output.add(list);
        }

        sc.close();

        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
            System.out.print("CountryCode="+output.get(i).get(0)+",");
            System.out.print("LocalAreaCode="+output.get(i).get(1)+",");
            System.out.print("Number="+output.get(i).get(2));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

It's giving me a IllegalStateException, meaning "no match found".

Comment: "But this regex doesn't match any input test case." Like what?

Comment: post your java code..

Comment: the output should be in format `CountryCode=1,LocalAreaCode=877,Number=2638277
CountryCode=91,LocalAreaCode=011,Number=23413627` there is not problem with reegx.improve the output format

Comment: @Tichodroma I've given an example,
posted the code

Comment: I believe the problem is with how you're reading the input.

Comment: Anything wrong with `input.split("-")`?

Comment: notive that the each conutry has an other splitting pattern. So for CountryCode=1 you can like that but for other Countrycodes this might be inappropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
package de.lhorn.stackoverflow;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern phoneNumber = Pattern
                .compile("^(\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{4,10})$");

        Matcher matcher = phoneNumber.matcher("1-425-9854706");
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
425
9854706
```

Comment: apparently it does....I found the error in my code. I haven't used a matching function like matches() or find(). Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Country Code    : 1  
Local Area Code : 425  
Number          : 9854706
```

You need to capture the groups in a while-loop, using the `find()` method on the `Matcher` object:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class PhoneRegexTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String line = "1-425-9854706";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{1,3})[- ](\\d{4,10})$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            printMatch("Country Code", matcher, 1);
            printMatch("Local Area Code", matcher, 2);
            printMatch("Number", matcher, 3);
        }
    }

    public static void printMatch(String label, Matcher m, int group) {
        System.out.printf("%-16s: %s%n", label, m.group(group));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hadn't used a matching function like matches() or find(), which was causing the exception

Answer (score 0):

The following expressions will parse a phone number, pulling the various parts from right to left, if they exist, ignoring non-digit separators.

```
.*?(?<country>[\d]*?)\D*(?<areacode>\d{0,3})\D*(?<prefix>\d{0,3})\D*(?<line>\d{0,4})$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for an application that accepts user input
//user input in the form (555) 555-5555

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneNumberTokenizer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter phone number to tokenize: ");

        String phoneNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] tokens = phoneNumber.split("\\D+");

        System.out.println("The tokens are: ");

        for(String token : tokens)
           System.out.println(token);

        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    int a =sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    int i =1;
    while(i<=a)
        {
        String s =sc.nextLine();
        String[] words =s.trim().split("[ -]");
        System.out.println("CountryCode="+words[0]+","+"LocalAreaCode="+words[1]+"," +"Number="+words[2]);
        i++;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

It might be easier to use the String.split function, in this example:

```
String fullNumber = "1-425-9854706";

String[] splitNumber = fullNumber.split("-");

String countryCode = splitNumber[0];  // 1
String areaCode = splitNumber[1];     // 425
String number = splitNumber[2];       // 9854706
```