# Split phone numbers like this +11234567890 into 123 in col 1 and 4567890 col 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is some sample data

```
phone_area_code phone_number
NULL    +11234567890
NULL    +11234567890
NULL    +11234567890
NULL    +11234567890
```

I am trying to get results like this

```
phone_area_code phone_number
123             4567890
123             4567890
123             4567890
123             4567890
```

Comment: If the data is consistent you can use the SUBSTRING() function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for splitting a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253503/regex-for-splitting-a-phone-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING()` to retrieve parts of a `VARCHAR` type. For example:

```
select
  substring(phone_number, 3, 3) as phone_area_code
  substring(phone_number, 6, 7) as phone_number
from t
```

Comment: You could substitute 7 with LEN(FieldName) - 3 if the length varies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT and RIGHT functions to arrive at area code and phone number

```sql
select LEFT(REPLACE(phone_number,'+1',''),3) AS phone_area_code,
       RIGHT(phone_number,7) AS phone_number
from 
(
values
(NULL    ,'+11234567890'),
(NULL    ,'+11234567890'),
(NULL    ,'+11234567890'),
(NULL    ,'+11234567890')
) as cte_phone(phone_area_code,phone_number)
```

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| phone_area_code | phone_number |
+-----------------+--------------+
|             123 |      4567890 |
|             123 |      4567890 |
|             123 |      4567890 |
|             123 |      4567890 |
+-----------------+--------------+
```